# What is pros and cons when setting large queue size? (ex:for mongo_db_plugin)

Tags: nodeos, full-node

looks like default value of 'mongodb-queue-size' is 256, What is difference between setting small size and large size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, if you set a small queue size, and your mongodb writing is slow, the queue will populate too fast that it reaches the capacity easily. This will cause the mongodb plugin to crash.

If you set a large queue size, your nodeos will consume more RAM.